# How to read array from db with a YEAR function

Tags: php, mysql

this is the select:

```
select distinct YEAR(ovl_dat) from db;
```

the array i get back looks like this:

```
Array ( 
[0] => stdClass Object ( [YEAR(ovl_dat)] => 1995 ) 
[1] => stdClass Object ( [YEAR(ovl_dat)] => 1957 ) 
[2] => stdClass Object ( [YEAR(ovl_dat)] => 1994 ) 
[3] => stdClass Object ( [YEAR(ovl_dat)] => 1982 ) 
[4] => stdClass Object ( [YEAR(ovl_dat)] => 1997 ) )
```

This is the code to read the array into option (joomla)

```
foreach($jaren as $enkeljaar) {
   $i++;
   $options[$i] = JHTML::_('select.option',$i ,$enkeljaar->YEAR(ovl_dat));
}
```

I have problems reading the $enkeljaar->YEAR(ovl_dat). Can someone tell me how to do that ?

regards Jan

Comment: your code is not enough  .. so the rest of code where your use the query result

Answer (score 1):

you  should use an alias for the columns name and

```
select distinct YEAR(ovl_dat) as my_year from db;
```

refer to alias name for get the value eg assuming your result is returne in $row

```
$row['my_year'];
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax to get/set object properties with arbitrary names is this:

```
$foo = (object)null;

$foo->{'[YEAR(ovl_dat)]'} = 2018;
$foo->{'One
Two->Three'} = 'Hi';

var_dump($foo->{'[YEAR(ovl_dat)]'}, $foo->{'One
Two->Three'});
```

([demo](https://3v4l.org/ig1pi))

However, unless you're in a code obfuscation contest you probably want to assign a proper name:

```
select distinct YEAR(ovl_dat) as distinct_year from db;
```